# Get specific values from same column within grouped rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

This is a problem for which I have a working query, but it feels horribly inefficient to me and I'd like some help constructing a better one. This is going into a live production environment, and the number of queries the db handles each day is incredibly high, so the more efficient this can be, the better. I have a table structured something like this (stripped to just the relevant parts):

```
id | type | datecolumn
1  | A    | 2014-01-01
1  | B    | 0000-00-00
2  | A    | 2014-01-02
2  | B    | 2014-01-10
3  | A    | 2014-01-01
3  | B    | 0000-00-00
```

There will always be two rows for each id, one of type A and one of type B. A will always have a valid date, and B will either have a date >= that of A, or all 0s. What I want is a query that will produce output similar to this:

```
id | date for A | date for B
1  | 2014-01-01 | None
2  | 2014-01-02 | 2014-01-10
3  | 2014-01-01 | None
```

The way I'm doing this now is as follows:

```
SELECT
    id,
    IF(MIN(datecolumn) > 0, MIN(datecolumn), MAX(datecolumn)) AS 'date for A',
    IF(MIN(datecolumn) > 0, MAX(datecolumn), 'None') AS 'date for B'
GROUP BY id
```

But it really feels like I should be able to pluck the datecolumn value on a by-type basis somehow. I know the simplest solution should be to change the table structure so that each id only uses one row, but I'm afraid that is not possible in this case; there has to be two rows. Is there a way to leverage the type column properly in this query?

Edit: Also, this is on a table that will have upwards of 10,000,000 rows. So again, efficiency is key.

Comment: I think this is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stick with what you've go, but maybe write it this way...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,datecolumn DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
,PRIMARY KEY(id,type)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'A','2014-01-01'),
(1  ,'B','0000-00-00'),
(2  ,'A','2014-01-02'),
(2  ,'B','2014-01-10'),
(3  ,'A','2014-01-01'),
(3  ,'B','0000-00-00');

 SELECT id
      , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN datecolumn END) a
      , MAX(REPLACE(CASE WHEN type='B' THEN datecolumn END,'0000-00-00','none')) b 
   FROM my_table 
  GROUP 
     BY id;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | a          | b          |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-01-01 | none       |
|  2 | 2014-01-02 | 2014-01-10 |
|  3 | 2014-01-01 | none       |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index that covers both the id and type columns (e.g `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX (type,id)`), then do:

```
SELECT
    table_a.id,
    table_a.datecolumn AS 'date for A',
    IF(table_b.datecolumn > 0, table_b.datecolumn, 'None') AS 'date for B'
FROM tbl AS table_a
JOIN tbl AS table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id AND table_b.type = 'B'
WHERE table_a.type = 'A';
```

Comment: If this is faster I'll eat my shorts.

Comment: This is a table that's going to have upwards of 10,000,000 rows. A self-join is not going to work.

Comment: Go for it - and let me know - although I really don;t fancy eating my shorts. They're my only pair.

Comment: Interestingly, on Windows 7 x64, Core i7-4700MQ @ 2.40Ghz with 16GB RAM (innodb_buffer_pool_size=8GB) and a 7200RPM WD5000BPKX your solution running against ~12million rows is x3 faster (roughly) on InnoDB, but x3 slower (roughly) on MyISAM...